# Cannot split string from a list to two parts

Tags: c#, .net, string

I'm trying to create an configuration file for my server program. I'm reading it line by line and when encounter desired option I'm processing that line. I have to extract IP written to file, but Visual Studio won't let me.
Here is code of process method:

```
////I'm assuming that file is loading is good...
private int processIp()
{
        String tempIpAddr = "";

        Console.Write("IP");
        for (int i = 0; i < readLines.Count; i++)
        {
            if (readLines[i].Contains("IP"))
            {
                if(readLines[i].Contains(":"))
                {
                    tempIpAddr = readLines.ElementAt(i).Split(':');
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
 }
```

I'm getting that error:Error    4   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'   F:\DB\Dropbox\Repozytoria\ARDSQL GUI\Sources\Configuration.cs   85  38  ARDSQL GUI

I tried changing `tempIpAddr` to array and changing this `readLines.ElementAt(i).Split(':');` to this `tempIpAddr = readLines[i].Split(':');`

How to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of `String.Split()` is a string array `string[]`.

Adjust your declaration to look like this:

```
String[] tempIpAddr;
```

Comment: Really? Uh, I should go to sleep...
Thank You for help :)

Comment: Could also set it to ` = null;` if you get any compiler errors trying to use the "uninitialized data" later on...

Comment: Based on his code, that wouldn't happen since the first use of the variable is in setting it.

Comment: @NathanA Personally I get the following trying to use it: "Error 1 Use of unassigned local variable 'tempIpAddr'" if I use it below the loop... Don't know which compiler you're using.

Comment: that is true if you add code below the loop... but as I said before, *based on his code*, it wasn't needed.  For all we know, he could use the value of that variable inside the loop, in which case, it's not needed.  You are not wrong, but it's extra info that's not directly related to the question.

Comment: @ebyrob: this is a legitimate error because readLines[i] might never contain a ':'.  So tempIpAddr may never be assigned to.

Comment: @ebyrob I'm using VS 2013 Express, it isn't raising any warnigs.

Comment: Whether there is a ':' in the string or not, Split() will *always* return a value and it will *always* be assigned to that variable.  So as long as the value is used inside the loop after the assignment statement, there is no need to declare it null at the beginning.

Comment: @NathanA His code was pretty obviously incomplete as it doesn't actually use the variable.  I was just pointing out that " = null;" gives a solution that will work regardless what he adds later on.  (Yes, readLines would have to be empty for this to matter but it is the compiler that burps on this regardless of what is in readLines.)

Comment: @NathanA: Yes, Split() always returns a value.  But if the string doesn't contain a ':', then Split() is never called, resulting in an unassigned variable.

Comment: @Klay or the loop may never be entered.

Comment: That is true, didn't notice the extra if statement. But if you end up using the variable outside of the loop, you'll only get the last value assigned, wasting all the previous values. Again, a mute point because it's obviously non-usable code and was meant only as an example.

Comment: @NathanA: Hence my comment below about "a few other problems".  This code should really be re-thought entirely.

Comment: @NathanA And yet, removing **ALL** if statements, I get the same error.  (And yes, it could be argued a useless error, I believe Java would just set it to null *for* you)  But it doesn't matter, you got lucky, he never hit the error.

Answer (score 1):

string.Split() returns an array of strings, and you are trying to assign that to a string variable , which won't work.

If you *know* that the IP address is always the string segment following the very first ':' on the line, and that there will be nothing following the IP address, you could modify your code thus:

```
tempIpAddr = readLines.ElementAt(i).Split(':')[1]
```

But trusting your client is a sure-fire way to fail.  And I would at least do a Trim() after the Split().

(There are a few other problems in your code, but you may already be aware of them: i.e. you aren't returning the temp IP address or doing anything else with it.)

Comment: Yes, i'm aware of them. It's fixed for now. I trust my client because if, there will be an error in configuration file, an exception or warning will be raised, and server won't proceed.